# Was creating model.manager and I believe I deleted the database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I am using Django 2.2.7, python 3.7.4 and windows 10.

I am following django docs to create a project.  I wanted to create a Queryset but I want to use my field names vs objects.  By following tutorial, I created model.Manager (or so I thought).  I executed `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` but in the migration file it appears I have deleted fields and maybe the DB, I'm not sure.

What I was attempting is:
DB name :district
change the two field names ("congressional_district and zcta) from "objects" and instead use their names in the Manager model to call specifically.  Did I confuse myself?

````
from django.db import models

class district(models.Model):
    congressional_district = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    zcta = models.IntegerField(default = 0, primary_key=True) #can integers be limited like Charfields?

    congressional_district = models.Manager()
    zcta = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.congressional_district} {self.zcta}' ```

Migration file
````

operations = [

```
migrations.AlterModelManagers(
    name='district',
    managers=[
        ('congressional_district', django.db.models.manager.Manager()),
    ],
),
 migrations.RemoveField(
     model_name='district',
     name='congressional_district',
 ),
 migrations.RemoveField(
     model_name='district',
     name='zcta',
 ),
 migrations.AddField(
     model_name='district',
     name='id',
     field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, default=django.utils.timezone.now, primary_key=True,
```

serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
         preserve_default=False,
      ),
]

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see you replace the variables of the fields for Managers so Django understands that you delete the variables from the models. If you run the migrate on Database of production you lost all the data

Comment: @JuanMiGabarron does this mean I have to delete/strip models.manager and reload all data?  I read the docs but apparently I don't understand why or when to use models.Manager.

Comment: Well model manager is used usually to have a humanize method to do query filters, you have a common manager "objects" on all the models, this is used by when you do `district.objects.all()` Imagine you want to have a filter like `district.objects.by_ zcta(zcta_number)` You need to do like:

class DistrictQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def by_zcta(self, number):
        return self.filter(zcta=number)

and then in your model:

class district(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = DistrictQuerySet()

Comment: @JuanMiGabarron, I am confused on zcta_number.  Is this a defined variable?